# Duplicate Xamarin Navbar Toolbar Items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm making an app in Xamarin Forms and when I deploy it to Android, I get a weird problem. It appears that I have two toolbar items when I only declared one in XAML. Also, I believe this is proper behaviour, but I was wondering if it's possible to not display the navbar title on a lower line and rather display it upper center. Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wanXR.png)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Biziboards.Views.MerchantListPage"
         Title="Merchants">

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Home" 
                 x:Name="btnHome" 
                 Clicked="btnHome_Clicked"
                 Order="Primary"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: This is a good article: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pages Xaml.cs file:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Comment: This solves the issues, but I've noticed that it makes the title disappear. Is there any way to still display the title?

Comment: You can have it to remove just a back button. Just use this code:
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
but this would still make it have 2 Nav bars, Your custom one and Android Default. Why dont you add Title in your Custom one and Bind it in PageModel?

Comment: I'm not using a custom one, I'm just setting the Title attribute to the ContentPage in XAML. I am not sure how I would make a custom Navbar but I would love to implement this!